# Use function to create a new column in a DataFrame based on DataFrame variables with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a function to assign a hex color variable based on a scale from `0-1`.

In one column I have pageviews that are being assigned a scale:

```
df1['pvScale'] = df1['GA Page Views']/max(df1['GA Page Views'])
```

But when I go to create another column and have that be based off a function for assigning `hex` values:

```
df1['hex'] = colorscale("#00ff4c", df1['pvScale']) #(orginal hex, 0-1)
```

Getting this return:

> ```
> "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."
> ```

What's the correct syntax to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df.apply()`:

```
df1['hex'] = df['pvScale'].apply(lambda x: colorscale("#00ff4c", x))
```

It will apply the `colorscale` function on the values in one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use .apply but didn't have the lambda function.